# Yii Sending parameters to index action through page url

Tags: php, yii, yii-routing

```
mysite/users triggers usersController index action.
```

Now I want to send `mysite/users/123` to usersController.

How Can I do it ? and where to will go this request if not to index action ?

Comment: @David do you want to just send 123 without key? or you want to change the representation of Url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated form comments discussion**

If you want to pass 123 to the controller you need to set the named parameter in the urlManager of the config/main.php file.

```
'something/<namedParameter:Pattern>' => 'MyControllerToCall/MyMethodofControllerToUse'
```

So for you:

```
'users/<username:\d+>' => 'users/view'
```

**In the view**

```
public function actionView($username){

echo $username;
}
```

That will only work in the view method though as the 123 part is being taken from the URL and you have configured Yii so when the url mysite/users/ is displayed like `mysite/users/123`. It calls the View method of the users Controller.

Comment: so If I write in config 'users'=>'usersController/view'
Then in controllers file I have
public function actionView($username){
and this '123' will go to $username variable ?

Comment: It needs to be `'users' => 'users/view'`. Then in that will call the `users` Controller and the `view` method. But no, it won't do that because you haven't passed anything to the left hand side of the rule. The other I answer I gave you will do what you ask. But that was for the url `users/123`. This rule you said `mysite/users`. But, normally I would say if you are having a url like `mysite/user`, then it would call the index (`users/index`) method and get all users. Then the url `users/123` is more specific and would call just the user with the username 123

Comment: Please forget my other question, there the story is a bit different from this. And here what I want to do is to pass this '123' data to any action of usersController, I want to trigger the controller and to test it I want to echo right there in action this '123'